Question about differentiable functions on manifolds
Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $\mathscr{C}(x) = \{\gamma : (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\to M : \gamma(0) = x, \gamma \text{ differentiable}\}$.
Let $x \in (U,\varphi)$ be a chart. In my textbook says that for $\gamma \in \mathscr{C}(x)$ we have that
$$ \frac{d(f\circ\gamma)}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0} = \frac{d(f \circ \varphi^{-1} \circ \varphi\circ \gamma)}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0} = \frac{\partial(f \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial u^i}\bigg\vert_{\phi(x)} \cdot \frac{d (\varphi \circ \gamma)^i}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0},$$
where $(u^i)$ are the coordinates on $\phi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^m$.
But I don't understand where this relation came from. And this is a vector or a sum ? (it has that $i$'s). It shouldn't be $$\frac{d(f\circ\gamma)}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0} =\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{\partial(f \circ \varphi^{-1})}{\partial u^i}\bigg\vert_{\phi(x)} \cdot \frac{d (\varphi \circ \gamma)^i}{dt}\bigg\vert_{t=0}?$$

This is just the chain rule. This is a sum. Look up Einstein summation notation/what text are you using to learn differential geometry, they should have established Einstein summation notation  early on…

@Chris so what I've said in the last row of my post it's ok?

for confirmation - yes your last line is correct.

Thanks! I looked in book after Einstein summation but I didn't find it. But now I understand!
